# Web Bluetooth bypass Pairing Screen for a known device id

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

Is it possible to connect a bluetooth device whose ID I know without the pairing screen?

```
classic:
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice ({filters: [{services: ['heart_rate']}]})
     .then (device => {
       this.device = device;
       return device.gatt.connect ();
```

instead I would like to do device.gatt.connect () without navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice .. at least for the device that I have already connected once or of which I know the ID.

can someone help me? ..thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Bluetooth Permissions API integration section of the Web Bluetooth spec](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#example-permission-api-query) does specify a way to do this using a device ID. However, it is not currently implemented in any browser.

There is ongoing work in Chrome to implement a `getDevices()` method that can return a list of previously granted Bluetooth devices. The status of that API can be checked in [Chrome Platform Status](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4797798639730688).

**6/22/20 Edit:**

I recently implemented a new permissions backend as well as two APIs that will enable previously permitted Bluetooth devices to be used.

The new permissions backend is implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend. The new backend will persist device permissions granted through [`requestDevice()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) until the permission is reset in Site Settings or the Page Info dialog box.

The [`getDevices()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices) and [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) are implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag for Chrome 85.0.4165.0 or greater. The recommended use of these APIs is to use `getDevices()` to retrieve an array of permitted BluetoothDevices and then calling `watchAdvertisements()` on these devices to start a scan. When advertisement packets are detected from the devices, the [`advertisementreceived`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#eventdef-bluetoothdevice-advertisementreceived) Event will be fired on the device that it corresponds to. At this point, the Bluetooth device is in range and can be connected to.

Please give this new feature a try, and file any bugs at https://crbug.com using the Blink>Bluetooth component.

Comment: thanks! ..I saw that there was news about getDecives () .. do you know where I can find an example?

Comment: There's not an example up yet, but this [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/pull/676) will add one once it is merged.

Comment: Any news on this,